# How can I manage to redirect old search URL into new search URL on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am working on friendly URL for search params... But i have na issue, for example:

The old URL would be something like this:

```
/c/professores-e-estudios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&alvo=&aprofundamento=&especialidade=&bairro=Jardim+Botanico&custom=
```

The new URL that I created is:

```
/c/professores-e-estudios?bairro=Jardim+Botanico
```

I tried on routes.rb

```
 get '/c/professores-e-estudios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&alvo=&aprofundamento=&especialidade=&bairro=Jardim+Botanico&custom=', to: redirect('/c/professores-e-estudios?bairro=Jardim+Botanico
')
```

It has created a loop.

I also tried on nginx file:

```
location = /c/professores-e-estudios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&alvo=&aprofundamento=&especialidade=&bairro=Jardim+Botanico&custom= { return 301 $scheme://mysite.com/c/professores-e-estudios?bairro=Jardim+Botanico; }
```

but nothing worked.

On Google Webmaster tool I get the message of duplicated page, did someone have the same problem? Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: why aren't you just making these params have default values? so if you're in your controller action method and none of these params are already passed you can set them with their default value? I don't think that the params are affecting on the url, both urls are the same.

Comment: You don't need to use nginx or redirect since the endpoint is the same. As @MahmoudSayed pointed out just use all the arguments with default value

Comment: Hi Mahmoud Sayed and Tarun Lalwani, the first URL was get in the "search form", that have 5 select fields, and the second one in a "tags cloud"... for me also they are the same, but i was working on SEO, and found out that the Google Webmaster Tool said that these "two pages" have duplicated content! Could you explain me about "just use default params", sorry, i didn't understand that! The idea of redirect was to unify both in one only address, i dont know if is possible with redirect or if is needed other solution.